# Unable to set the parent of a dynamically created QML component

Tags: qt, qml

I am creating dynamic component in QML as follows:

```
var component = Qt.createComponent("PlayerWindow.qml")
if (component.status != component.errorString())
    console.log(component.errorString())
var playerWin = component.createObject(rootWindow);
```

Here `rootWindow` is my main application window. Now, the `PlayerWindow` is quite simple as:

```
Window {
    id: playerWindow
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(parent.width)
        console.log(rootWindow.height)
    }
}
```

The thing is that the values for `parent.width` and `rootWindow.width` are really different and this is also evident when the window is displayed. However, `rootWindow` is set as the parent in the `createObject` call. So, I am not sure what is happening there but I wanted to know if this is the correct way to set the component parent when they are being dynamically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `console.log(parent)` in the code. You will see something like `qml: QQuickRootItem(0x1e3e4e0)`. If you check the Qt doc you will find that [Item.parent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#parent-prop) returns `Item` but Windows is not `Item`descendant but `QQuickWindow`. Also from documentation:

> A QQuickWindow always has a single invisible root item ...

So, in your case `parent` and `rootWindow` are different objects.

P.S. The dynamic object creation in your code can produce an error since `component.createObject` will be executed although `Qt.createComponent` returns error. Just copy the code from [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method).